# Получить из объекта нужные поля

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Как можно сократить такой код  JS:

```js
// есть некоторый массив с объектами
var fruits = [{
    id: ...,
    name: ...,
    type: ...,
    // other fields
}];

// нужно получить массив с подготовленными объектами,
// где содержатся только нужные поля
var prepared = fruits.map((fruit) => {
    return {
        id: fruit.id, // как здесь не копипастить id два раза подряд?
        name: fruit.name, // а здесь name ..
    }
});
```

Comment: es6 а сами var пишите

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rNOeYxG вот так

Comment: я думал, что можно использовать что-то вроде: `return ({ id, name } = fruit);` - но в таком случае возвращается весь объект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fruitList = [
    genFruit(null, null, null)
];
const prepared = fruitList.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name, }))
function genFruit(id, name, type ) { return { id, name, type } }
```

- Деструктуризация - https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring

Comment: имена тем не менее придется продублировать, но видимо, по другому никак)

Comment: нууу, если их много - можно так `const prepared = fruitList.map(({ type, ...other }) => other)`